# Facebook OpenGraph internationalization

Tags: facebook, internationalization, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to implement internationalisation with facebook og tags, in order to have the object created on the page with the right language when shared.

This are the meta tags rendered when the page is requested as normal:

```
<meta property="og:ttl" content="120" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Clioco Make Up Bundle" />
<meta property="og:description" content="The more people who take part in Clioco Make Up Bundle&#39;s giveaway, the more free stuff everyone gets. So sign up now and tell your friends!" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="1436786566" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://clioco.cobuydev.com/cobuys/clioco-make-up-bundle" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_CA" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://res.cloudinary.com/hp0f8ghfo/image/upload/v1429186395/ibawbi5rfdjwebcqf8er.png" />
```

This are the meta tags rendered when you specify the `fb_locale` param as `fb_locale=fr_CA`:

```
<meta property="og:ttl" content="120" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="FR Clioco Make Up Bundle" />
<meta property="og:description" content="FR FR FR FR The more people who take part in FR Clioco Make Up Bundle&#39;s giveaway, the more free stuff
everyone gets. So sign up now and tell your friends!
" />
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="1436786566" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://clioco.cobuydev.com/cobuys/clioco-make-up-bundle" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="fr_FR" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_CA" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="en_GB" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://res.cloudinary.com/hp0f8ghfo/image/upload/v1429186395/ibawbi5rfdjwebcqf8er.png" />
```

So, after made it work correctly, I have been trying to share this link from a facebook account that have main language setted up to be fr_CA, but the generated card is still in English.

I also wasn't able to test the render of it in fr_CA using the debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fclioco.cobuydev.com%2Ffr%2Fcobuys%2Fclioco-make-up-bundle&fb_locale=fr_FR)

Can someone tell me what am I missing? (if I'm missing something :D)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This currently works for Open Graph stories only – for normal posts, it is not supported. (This has been confirmed by a Facebook employee in the FB developers group.)

Comment: Thank you very much! This wasn't specified in the documentation :)

Comment: Side note: You do realize that the `og:ttl` metatag value is in seconds, and you have it set for a miniscule 120 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Answering our own question, we discussed this on a Facebook bug report and after a bit of back and forth, came to the same conclusion as @CBroe commented.

It is not possible.

For further information see https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/978849008813532